# How to group flux elements by LocalDate?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Given a `Flux<Event>` where Event is:

```
data class Event(val eventDate: LocalDate, val data: String)
```

I would like to group the Flux elements by their event date in ascending order, considering that there will be elements that happen at the exact same LocalDate.

The goal is to end up having something like `Flux<GroupedEvent>` where `GroupedEvent` is:

```
data class GroupedEvent(val eventDate: LocalDate, val data: List<String>)
```

Notice `data: List<String>` will contain all data that happened at the same `LocalDate`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given data structure:

```
public class GroupedEvent {
    private LocalDate localDate;
    private List<String> data;
}
public class Event {
    private LocalDate eventDate;
    private String data;
}
```

You can try this way:

```
        List<Event> data = Arrays.asList(
                new Event(LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 1), "A"),
                new Event(LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 2), "B"),
                new Event(LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 3), "C"),
                new Event(LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 1), "D"),
                new Event(LocalDate.of(2019, 2, 1), "E")
        );

        Flux<Event> eventFlux = Flux.fromIterable(data);
        Flux<GroupedFlux<LocalDate, Event>> groupedFluxFlux = eventFlux.groupBy(Event::getEventDate);
        groupedFluxFlux.flatMap(groupedFlux ->
                groupedFlux
                        .map(Event::getData)
                        .collectList()
                        .map(list -> new GroupedEvent(groupedFlux.key(), list))
        )
                .sort(Comparator.comparing(GroupedEvent::getLocalDate))
                .doOnNext(groupedEvent -> System.out.println(groupedEvent.getLocalDate() + " -> " + groupedEvent.getData()))
                .subscribe();
```

Comment: Hi @mslowiak, your solution is almost right but there seems to be a problem with the ordering, it shows: `2019-01-03 -> [C], 2019-01-02 -> [B], 2019-01-01 -> [A, D], 2019-02-01 -> [E]`, when it should be `2019-01-01 -> [A, D], 2019-01-02 -> [B], 2019-01-03 -> [C], 2019-02-01 -> [E]`

Comment: @codependent Yeah, sorry I forgot about sorting. I updated the answer.